# Line select for modification

Tags: macos, keyboard, windows

I have used Microsoft Windows for 15+ years and am a highly keyboard-centric user. My wife uses both iMac and MacBook Pro, which means a full keyboard and a MacBook keyboard. Occasionally, I use her computers to see if I can migrate to Apple world. Web-surfing and video-watching are okay, but I find myself stressed by using MacBook keyboards and Mac when I work. Please teach me how I can do the following jobs or solve these problems:

1. <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> : When I edit text (like in MS Word) in Windows, I many times use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to select a line if I am at the end of the line, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select a line if I am at the beginning of the line. I am not with a Mac now so I can't remember, but I remember such a line-selecting resulted in a different result in Mac. I guess it went to the page top with <kbd>Home</kbd>. Can I change Mac keyboard setting so that I get the same behavior for line selection?
2. How can I do the above line selection task using a MacBook keyboard (with no visible <kbd>home</kbd>/<kbd>end</kbd> keys)?

Comment: [TextMate Blog » Key bindings for switchers](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/)

Comment: @Lri Thanks for the post. The post also led to a key binding software, http://www.cocoabits.com/KeyBindingsEditor/

Comment: You'll get better results with one question per question post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! As mentioned, you need to ask each question separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lion now has the behavior you expect in #3.

To do line selection, use command and the left and right arrow keys. Add shift to select.
(Command-left to replace Home, Command-right to replace End.)

Comment: arrow keys should work, but I prefer working with home and end keys, to avoid pressing arrow, arrow, arrow, arrow, arrow ... or arroooooooooooooooooooooooooooow.

Comment: Thanks for the information re #3. I'm glad that Lion behave like it!

Comment: holding command and arrows keys make them act as page up/down and home/end keys. Never knew anyone ever used those though, seems so inefficient

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX I never learned to use home/end and page up/down, so the command-arrow stuff is very natural. I hold Command with my index finger and hit the arrow keys with my ring or pinky fingers.

Comment: @Chang Hold Command and hit the left arrow is the same as Home on Windows - no need for multiple arrow key presses.

Comment: i just find that using the  mouse to be much faster because i can highlight and rearrange text just by dragging

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX But you remove your hand away from the keyboard, control your mouse, and put your hand back on the keyboard. Home/End is usually closer than the mouse. Also, arrow keys and touchpad are closer to your body than home/end, so moving a hand to arrow keys/touchpad creates some discomfort in the wrist or make the entire arm move, at least to me.

Comment: @CajunLuke Sorry, I missed `Command part. Home on Mac full keyboard is not same as Home on Windows. Command+LeftArrow on any Mac keyboard is same as Home on Windows. Am I correct? In addition, is Shift+LeftArrow on Mac same as on Windows? Since I'm not with a Mac now, I can't test.

Comment: @Chang That's correct. Command-Arrows is the alternative to the Windows behavior. I don't know anybody who actually uses the Mac behavior of Home/End.

Answer (score 1):

You select a line on a Mac by holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> (to start the selection), and <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>.

Please ask your last question in a separate thread because it differs significantly.
This will allow community to benefit from a searchable question with a specific title.